# Positive semi-definiteness of difference of two positive matrices: prove or disprove

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, positive-semidefinite

I am doing an exercise created by myself :). Let
$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}, C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times p}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times q}, E \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times q}$ be any real matrices and Let $$M_{1}=A^{\top} A+C^{\top} C$$
$$
M_{2}=\left(A^{\top} B+C^{\top} E\right)\left(E^{\top} E+B^{\top} B+I_{q}\right)^{-1}\left(B^{\top} A+E^{\top} C\right)
$$
obviously $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ are positive semidefinite matrix, prove that $M_{1}-M_{2}$ is also positive semidefinite matrix, i.e minimum eigenvolue of $M_{1}-M_{2}$ bigger than 0 .

My approach: I try SVD and expand $M_{2}$ but I don't know how to analyze the cross-product term. I run many simulations in which the entries of $A,B,C,E$ are from i.i.d Gaussian. In all simulations the minimum eigen-value of $M_1-M_2$ is greater than zero.(I set p=q=n=10,m=300)

I wonder if someone can help me prove this or give me an counter example on above statement.

Oh, I think I prove it, my approach is that:
Let
$$W=\left(\begin{array}{c}
B  \\
E 
\end{array}\right),Q=\left(\begin{array}{c}
A  \\
C 
\end{array}\right)$$
Then $M_1=Q^TQ,\quad M_2=Q^TW(W^TW+I_q)^{-1}W^TQ \Rightarrow M_1\succ M_2$

Comment: I can only prove the simple case: $B$ and $E$ are diagonal matrix, which is straightforward to check $x^T (M_1-M_2)x \geq 0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^p$

Comment: Your proof is not really complete so far. You just draw the conclusion you want without really proving it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this problem, and thanks user 1551 for completing the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach works, but your have yet to explain why $Q^TQ\succeq Q^TW(W^TW+I_q)^{-1}W^TQ$. Observe that $W(W^TW+I_q)^{-1}W^T$ share the same set of nonzero eigenvalues with $W^TW(W^TW+I_q)^{-1}=I_q-(W^TW+I_q)^{-1}$. Hence all eigenvalues of $W(W^TW+I_q)^{-1}W^T$ are between $0$, and $1$ and $I_{n+m}\succeq W(W^TW+I_q)^{-1}W^T$. In turn, $Q^TQ\succeq Q^TW(W^TW+I_q)^{-1}W^TQ$.

An easier approach is to note that $M_1-M_2$ is the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of the bottom right diagonal sub-block of
$$
P=\pmatrix{A^T&C^T\\ B^T&E^T}\pmatrix{A&B\\ C&E}+\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&I_q}.
$$
Since $P$ is positive semidefinite, the Schur complement $M_1-M_2$ in $P$ must also be positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration!